# Blocking users UID using PAM

Tags: server, pam

So i have to block users by their UID, users that have uid >= 500 should not be able to login. This as to be done with the file common-auth with pam_sucess_if.so . i have tried:

auth        requisite     pam_succeed_if.so uid >= 500 quiet

with no sucess.
Does anyone know how to do this?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The `man pam_succeed_if` page has `flags` like `quiet` *before* `conditions` like `uid >= 500`.

```
auth requisite pam_succeed_if.so quiet uid >= 500
```

NOTE: I did not test this, I just read the `man` page.